# Problem converting Expression<Func<T, bool>> to query DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I want to query a DbSet in a generic way.

I have a method that returns me an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` for passing into a Where clause. I need to convert it to `Expression<Func<MyTypeHere, bool>>` but I have tried casting and it won't compile.

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> lambda = PrimaryKeyFilterExpression(id);

List<AuditDocumentContextEntity> eqmsAuditTrail =
                _eqmsDbContext.AuditDocumentContexts.Where(lambda)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToList();
```

Compilation error:

> Error CS1503  : cannot convert from
>   `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TEntity, bool>>` to
>   `System.Func<AuditTrail.Entities.AuditDocumentContextEntity, bool>`

Comment: Is this your real code? What is `TEntity` here?

Comment: `IQueryable` support is much more limited compared to `IEnumerable`. This was due to the fact `IQueryable` from EF need to be translated into sql queries and it have no idea what your `PrimaryKeyFilterExpression(id)` do.. thats why you get that error..